# macOS Sierra: How do you enable shutdown keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Opt + Cmd + Power)?

Tags: keyboard, shutdown, macos

After upgrading to macOS Sierra yesterday, I notice that the system keyboard shortcut to shut down the computer no longer works.

[As documented here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), before the upgrade you could shut down the computer using *Control–Option–Command–(Power button or Media Eject)*.

After the upgrade, the system seems to ignore the "Control–Option–Command" combo and merely sleep the display as if I had tapped the Power button alone.

Do you know of any documentation on how to restore the old shortcut?

Comment: I think this is a bad advice. Holding the power button for 5 seconds will just turn off the machine. All open documents will not be saved/cached and are thus gone.

Comment: surly its just easier to press the power button, then select shutdown?

Comment: I found the issue: https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/124

Before upgrading to macOS Sierra, I was using the Seil app. Immediately after upgrading, Seil generated a notification that it wasn't compatible with the kernel. I went to the site to get a new version, and found a notice from the developer suggesting that Seil users download Karabiner Elements instead.

Uninstalling Karabiner Elements resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + Cmd + Opt + Power/Eject still works in macOS Sierra. I just tested it with an upgraded install (El Capitan to Sierra) on an MBP Mid-2014. Please see if another keyboard shortcuts overrides the shutdown command:

**System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts**

After upgrading to macOS Sierra my keyboard shortcut for Spotlight (CMD + Space) was changed to Ctrl + Space. I had to change it manually to restore the functionality.

Edit:
John, please do the following: Backup all PLIST-files starting with com.apple. + pbs.plist + ".GlobalPreferences.plist (in Terminal:

```
cp -f ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist ~/Desktop
# this will copy the file as a backup to the Desktop

rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
# this will delete the original file
```

Also backup the folder `~/Library/Caches/`. Now delete everything inside this folder. Empty the trash and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, oa-. I don't see any overlapping shortcuts in the Keyboard pref pane, but I did notice (through experimentation) that Siri was using the same shortcut as Quicksilver. That wasn't noted in the Keyboard Shortcuts panel though, so I don't think that it shows a comprehensive list of possible conflicts.

Comment: Can you please try to use the shutdown keyboard shortcut on a newly created user (administrator, not a standard user). If it works on the new account it can be related to your settings in your user profile. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, oa-—that worked: I created a test profile with administrative privileges, and the shutdown command worked instantly. Now I know that the problem is based on the state of my default profile. Do you know any further steps I could take to diagnose it?

Comment: Awesome! Yes, you can do the following: In Finder go to "~/Library/Preferences" (CMD+Shift+G). Locate the following files and copy them to your desktop: com.apple.Preferences.plist, com.apple.finder.plist, com.apple.HIToolbox.plist, com.apple.dock.plist. Now, delete one PLIST-file, empty your trash (CMD + Shift + Opt + Backspace) and restart your Mac. If this did not resolve the issue, try the next PLIST-file and restart. Please report back which PLIST-file enabled you to use the keyboard shortcut again.

Comment: Thanks again. I deleted the plist files you highlighted one by one, exactly as you described, restarting after each and trying the shortcut again. The shutdown command still doesn't work in my default profile. I still have the files I copied to Desktop. Any ideas what I can do next?

Comment: John, thanks for reporting back. In this case do the following: Backup all PLIST-files starting with com.apple. + pbs.plist + ".GlobalPreferences.plist (in Terminal: cp -f ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist ~/Desktop
(this will copy the file as a backup to the Desktop)

rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
(this will delete the original file) (to your desktop) and remove them at the same time. Also backup the folder "~/Library/Caches/". Now delete everything _inside_ this folder. Empty the trash and reboot.

Comment: That worked!  The shutdown shortcut is back. Do I need to do anything with the .plist files I backed up?

Comment: Terrific! You can keep them in case you notice that some of your applications' customizations are missing. I wish you a great weekend!

Comment: If you want to update your answer, I'll check it as the accepted solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, my success with this solution was short-lived. :( Two days later, the shortcut is no longer working. I nuked the designated plist  files again, and this time it didn't restore the keyboard command. In the interim, the only notable configurations I did were removing "mirroring options" from the menu bar and changing my clock setting to 24-hour time—and a few other things like that. Are there any further steps I can take to identify the root of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the keyboard shortcut with the other administrator user account since it happened?  The root of the issue lies within the ~/Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same. Used to shut down by holding power button for 1.5 sec. That feature seems to be gone with Sierra. This shortcut seems to work now: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> will bring up the window for shutting down.

Found here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), there are two shortcuts for shutdown:

> **Control–Option–Command–Power button** or 
>   Control–Option–Command–Media Eject

I tried the power-button shortcut on my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 with macOS Sierra 10.12.4 and it worked similar to the old eject-button shortcut (maybe a little slower, but that could be the new OS). I assume Apple added the additional shortcut for newer devices that don't have optical drives and eject buttons, but they neglected to maintain the eject-button shortcut for the older machines within the Sierra update. Just more infinite wisdom from Apple.

UPDATE: I found that the standard **Control–Option–Command–Media Eject** does indeed work with Sierra. It seems that, at least on my machine, the key remapping program [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and the Sierra-compatible version [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md) causes the Eject button to not register at all. When I disable Karabiner, the shutdown shortcut works normally. I did, however, find that Karabiner Elements does allow another key to be remapped as Eject. This won't work well on the limited internal keyboard, but for the external wired keyboard I set up one of the useless function keys (F19) as the Eject button. Now, **Control–Option–Command–F19** works with the external keyboard and shuts down the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Work around:  system Preferences> Shortcuts > Move Focus To The Menu bar (which is CTRL F2)  Turn that on, and use it to navigate to the Apple Icon, then use your Down Key to Navigate to Shut Down, or Restart or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

You can press

> "Ctrl + Fn + F1"

and the window will pop up with options to

> `"Restart, Sleep, Cancel, Shutdown"`

Do selection using

> "Ctrl + Tab" and press "Enter"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Also with fn + power. Then select Shut Down with return key.